# iOS - UIView Always on Front without BringSubviewToFront

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Can I have some **UIView** which will always appear on top in iOS?

There are lots of `addSubview` in my project but I need to have one small view which will always appear. SO is there any other option than

```
[self.view bringSubViewToFront:myView];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more option (especially if you want to overlap several screens, with logo for example) - separate UIWindow. Use `windowLevel` to set the level of new window.

```
UILabel *devLabel = [UILabel new];
devLabel.text = @" DEV ";
devLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
devLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[devLabel sizeToFit];

CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
static UIWindow *notificationWindow;
notificationWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:
                                CGRectMake(screenSize.width - devLabel.width, screenSize.height - devLabel.height,
                                devLabel.width, devLabel.height)];
notificationWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
notificationWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
notificationWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
notificationWindow.rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
[notificationWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:devLabel];
notificationWindow.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is set `layer.zPosition` of your `UIView.`

You need to add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Framework to your `.m file.`

And set such like

```
myCustomView.layer.zPosition = 101;// set maximum value as per your requirement.
```

For more information about [`layer.zPosition` read this documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition)

> **Discussion**
>   The default value of this property is 0. Changing the value of this property changes the the front-to-back ordering of layers onscreen. This can affect the visibility of layers whose frame rectangles overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to add other subviews below this always-on-top subview. For example:

```
[self.view insertSubview:subview belowSubview:_topSubview];
```

There's no solution with Interface Builder if you search for this kind. It should be done programmatically. If you don't want to use `bringSubviewToFront:` everytime, just insert other subviews below this one.

Answer (score 0):

Many times your view did not appear in viewDidLoad or, if your view comes from parentViewController (for example in many transitions like modal segue..) your can see parentViewController only in viewDidAppear so:

Try to put bringSubviewToFront in :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view bringSubViewToFront:myView];
// or if your view is attached in parentViewController
    [self.parentViewController.view bringSubViewToFront:myView];
}
```

Good luck!